# How to copy a specific docker image layer from one host to another?

Tags: docker

While I have a very big docker image (~5G) used for Android development, it's always failed when pulling a specific layer `72165266f070` which is about 3.1G as it carried Android NDK.

> 72165266f070: Error pulling dependent layers 
>   FATA[0217] Error pulling image (latest) from magicvision/android-dev, Server error: Status 403 while fetching image layer (72165266f0702fd767e1323770e8e4c9f8d01d1414cb6f42e352a69dba43e133)

I have the docker image in one of my hosts, so I want to copy the failed layer to remote. I don't want to copy the entire image with `docker save`/`docker load`, what I want is just copy that image layer.

Comment: Why not only save the failed layer by issuing command `docker save -o failed_layer.tar 72165266f070` ?

Comment: Do you also happen to know how to load the single layer back into the "base image" (that doesn't contain it)? Without the load command saving a layer isn't very useful...